# python prog which accept paragraph and scramle all the words in it

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have tried randomint .This is used to read a paragraph in from a file and then write the output to a file. I have code , but need help because it is not working quite as it should. Punctuation also needs to remain untouched.  Need it completed by tomorrow

is there anyone who can help me out??

```
import random
print("This program reads text from a file, then scrambles the letters within each word, except for the first and last letter.")
print("It then writes the scrambled words to a file of your choice.")
file_str = input("Please enter a file name that you would like scrambled: ")
def scramble():
    #prompt for user input file name
    input_file = open(file_str)
    #for each line in the file, split the words
    for line in input_file:
        words = line.split()
        #only take middle letters, leaving first and last letter
        word = list(words[1:-1])
        #scramble words
        r = random.randint(1, len(word)-1)
        output.append(word[-1])
        #scrambled word = first letter + scrambled + last letter
        scrambled = word[0] + " ".join(output)
    print(scrambled)
    input_file.close()
    output_file_str = input("Which file would you like to write this to?: ")
    output_file = open(output_file_str, 'a+')
    output_file.write(scrambled)
    output_file.close()
    print("Thank you. Your scrambled text has been written to the file. Goodbye.")

scramble()
output_file_str = input("Which file would you like to write this to?: ")
output_file = open(output_file_str, 'a+')
output_file.write(scrambled)
output_file.close()
print("Thank you. Your scrambled text has been written to the file. Goodbye.")
scramble()
```

Comment: your code doesn't seem to be valid. `output` is not defined, the method does not return anything, also  why do you call `scramble()` twice?

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to modify word characters (leaving punctuation in place), I'd suggest reading the whole text of your file at once and using using regular expressions to match the words. The `re.sub` function can replace each matched word with a scrambled version:

```
import random
import re

def scramble_word(word):
    if len(word) <= 3:    # short words don't have enough letters to shuffle
       return word

    first, *middle, last = word    # fancy unpacking! middle will be a list
    random.shuffle(middle)    # this modifies the list in place
    return first + "".join(middle) + last   # rejoin into a single string

def scramble_text(text):
    return re.sub(r"\w+", lambda match: scramble_word(match.group()), text)

def scramble_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()

    scrambled_text = scramble_text(text)

    with open(output_filename, "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write(scrambled_text)
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how best to call `scramble_file` with the filenames you get by asking the user.

Comment: the fancy unpacking part unfortunately works only in python 3+.

Comment: @lesingerouge fortunately, the question is tagged `[python-3.5]`! though alternate unpacking could be done with `first, middle, last = word[0], word[1:-1], word[-1]` if other portability is needed